# how to delete set in c++ or how to resize the set to 0

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to resize the set to 0 but it's giving an error on line 16. How can I resize the set to empty set? In line 16 the resize algorithm is giving an error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    set<int> p;
    set<int> a[2];
    p.insert(0);
    p.insert(1);
    a[0] = p;
    a[0].insert(3);
    set<int>::iterator it;

    for (it = a[0].begin(); it != a[0].end(); ++it)
        std::cout << ' ' << *it;

    a[0].resize(0);
    cout << a[0].size();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a[0].clear(); ?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but `std::set` doesn't have a `resize()` method

Comment: Try reading [a reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `clear` method of `std::set`

Answer (score 1):

std::set does not have a resize member. Perhaps you were thinking of std::vector?

But for any STL container, the idiomatic way to clear it is with the clear().

```
a[0].clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

std::set doesn't have resize function.
Use clear() method of std::set container

```
a[0].clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete `a` (set of integers), as follows:

```
std::set<int>().swap(a);
```